# Format Excel cell to text while exporting by PHP

Tags: php, mysql, excel

When I create an excel file and export it via php, it converts one particular cell "BATCH" to time format.  I want all cells to be by default text.  Can I actually alter the code to such?

```
mysql_select_db("Famhouse") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'LATIN5'");
mysql_query("SET character_set_connection = 'LATIN5'");
mysql_query("SET character_set_client = 'LATIN5'");
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'LATIN5'");
$header .="\t\t Batch Export
\t\t ".$_GET['c']." Production Batches \n\t\t\n\n";


$select = "select fname as 'First Name', sname as 'Second Name', tbatch as 'Batch'";


$export = mysql_query ( $select ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error( ) );

$fields = mysql_num_fields ( $export );


for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ )
{
    $header .= mysql_field_name( $export , $i ) . "\t";
}

while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $export ) )
{
    $line = '';
    foreach( $row as $value )
    {                                            
        if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )
        {
            $value = "\t";
        }
        else
        {
            $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
            $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
        }
        $line .= $value;
    }

    $data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
}
$data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );

if ( $data == "" )
{
    $data = "\n(0) Records Found!\n";                        
}

header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$_GET['dt']."-pbatch.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
print "$header\n$data"; //}
```

Comment: If you're writing a csv format file, why not use PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function

Comment: So what type of data values are in your `tbatch` column?

Comment: @MarkBaker tbatch as v.archar in the db, but it comes as time in the excel sheet

Comment: No, what type of values, e.g. if it contains a string like "01:00" then it will get converted to a time, because Excel's csv importer recognises that format as one that typically is associated with a time value

Comment: @MarkBaker it comes in as `abc 3` OR `10 a`

Comment: Then you've found a bug in MS Excel, better tell Microsoft about it

Comment: @MarkBaker LOL.. you must be kidding.. I have never encountered such error.  Can I not change the 'format' of each cell data to 'text'.

Comment: Nor have I ever encountered such an error: You're using a csv file, so you have absolutely no control at all over what MS Excel does with the values as they pass through the importer if you're loading the file via a double click.... you can only control it if you open MS Excel and select File/Open and use theCSV import wizard

Comment: An alternative is to create a real BIFF or OfficeOpenXML format file, where the cell types are specifically identified as number/string/Boolean/etc

Comment: @MarkBaker The file is downloaded as 'excel' not 'csv'.

Comment: The file you're creating is a csv format file, with a tab separator.... giving it an .xls extension does not automagically make it a native format BIFF of OfficeOpenXML format file.... because it's a csv file, it goes through MS Excel's csv importer